# Ambiguous reference to member 'collectionView' Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem changing the Layout of UICollectionView from Flow to Custom.

I referenced the address 
"https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest"

I tried adding the example code to the existing code

```
override func viewDidLoad () 
{
    super.viewDidLoad ()

    self.setViewLayer ()
    self.addPullToRefresher ()
    self.addGesture ()
    self.addDropDownView ()
    self.getArtList ()
    self.artCollectionView.regCells (cells: ["HomeCollectionViewCell"])

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.getNotification(_:)), name: Notification.Name(Constants.GET_ARTS), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.resetArts(_:)), name: Notification.Name(Constants.GET_ARTS_RESET), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.searchArts(_:)), name: Notification.Name(Constants.HOME_SEARCH), object: nil)
        
    if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? PinterestLayout
    {
        layout.delegate = self
    }
}

extension HomeViewController: PinterestLayoutDelegate
{
    func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return photos [indexPath.item].image.size.height
    }  
}
```

But I am getting an error at

```
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? PinterestLayout
```

Error states

> Ambiguous reference to member 'collectionView (_: willDisplay: forItemAt :)'

Please help me.

Comment: Can you add more code which you copied, because I am not able to see the will display cell method

Comment: Sorry. I did not analyze all the code because I was delegated to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on other code in `viewDidLoad`, your collection view variable is named `artCollectionView`, not `collectionView`. The error is really misleading in this case.

Change:

```
if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? PinterestLayout
```

to:

```
if let layout = artCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? PinterestLayout
```

Comment: Fixed a two day troublesome error! StackOverFlow is great! Thank you very much.

Comment: would you mind having a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59889660/ambiguous-reference-to-member-collectionview-layoutminimumlinespacingforsect