# Ambiguous reference to member 'collectionView(_:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt:)'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have found an error in my code that is really annoying me. I coded Swiping View Controller in a separate application and now I am trying to integrate it into this new application.

here is how view controller class is layed out:

```
class SwipingController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
```

Basically the error is as follows:

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'collectionView(_:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt:)'
```

here is some of my code, let me know if I need to add more!!

```
extension SwipingController {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! PageCell

        let page = pages[indexPath.item]
        //let page = pages[indexPath.row]
        cell.page = page
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }

}
```

the error happens on every mention of "CollectionView" in the main view controller

```
 @objc private func handleNext() {
        let nextIndex = min(pageControl.currentPage + 1, pages.count - 1)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: nextIndex, section: 0)
        pageControl.currentPage = nextIndex
        collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
```

I am also now getting the error:

```
Value of type 'SwipingController' has no member 'collectionViewLayout'
```

Which happens on this page:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (_) in
            self.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

            if self.pageControl.currentPage == 0 {
                self.collectionView?.contentOffset = .zero
            } else {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.pageControl.currentPage, section: 0)
                self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
            }

        }) { (_) in

        }
    }
```

let me know if I need to add more code in please!

Comment: Please show more context. In particular, have you declared that SwipingController conforms to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout?

Comment: @matt thank you for taking the time to comment! can you please suggest what code I should be displaying? also I have updated question to show how it conforms to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Comment: OK that's great, but what you are saying is still very mysterious because you keep talking rather vaguely as if there were _two different_ view controllers in the story. Sometimes there is the SwipingController and sometimes there is the "main view controller". How do they relate to one another? Which one holds the collection view? You cannot expect the "main view controller" to know what `collectionView?.scrollToItem` means, if SwipingController is the collection view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by wrestling with it for a few hours:

My major problem was the view controller in the storyboard was a view controller and not a collection view controller.

Thank you to all who helped!

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears because you are trying to use the variable `collectionView` in your `ViewController` when this are not declare yet, to solve this you need to declare it as follows.

Swift 5.x:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView?
```

This generates an `IBOutlet` which you can use to connect the variable created with the `UICollectionView` from your storyboard. Also **don’t forget** to connect the `delegate` and the `dataSource` with `ViewController` that will implement it.

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

For more information about how to implement the `UICollectionView` click [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview):

As a personal recommendation I would say at the moment you declare UI variables, as `UIView`, `UILabel` or in this case an `UICollectionView`, use prefix to maintain an order and suitable nomenclature.

For example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var clvPages: UICollectionView?
```

Hope this helps you, I’ll stay tuned to your comments.

Comment: thank you for your answer, Im a little confused. does creating this page programatically mean that I have to use storyboards to fix this?

Comment: if you have a chance to explain further, I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: thank you for your help, your answer got me thinking!